# I'm using a series of if/else statements, but instead of letting me "go through" them when I run, it goes straight to the last else statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

(beginner here using c# on visual studio who's testing out if/else statements) I have two windows open in Visual studio, one where I create the classes I need:

```
{
       public string firstName { get; set; }
       public string lastName { get; set; }

        public string fullName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName + lastName;
            }
        }


    }
```

and one with all my if/else statements:

```
{
            Person person = new Person();
            person.firstName = "John";
            person.lastName = "Doe";
            if (person.fullName == "John Doe")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welp... you've passed... you want another test?");
                string x = Console.ReadLine();
                if (x == "Yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Alright... what's 1+1?");
                    string y = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (y == "2")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Yay! You're right!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("oop... that's wrong my dude");
                    }

                }
                 else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lame... guess  that's bye for now.");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("oop... ya didn't pass. guess that's bye for now.");
            }

        }
```

When I run this, instead of letting me go through all the if/else statements, it brings me straight to the last else statement, and prints `oop... ya didn't pass. guess that's bye for now.` Sorry about the length, and anything that was confusing (I'm still working on my vocabulary haha) Thanks for taking the time for a beginner.

Comment: When you concatenate the names, they will be combined without space between them

Answer (score 2):

`fullName` is not including a space in the name thus the result is `JohnDoe` instead of `John Doe`.

Simply change:

```
 public string fullName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName + lastName;
            }
        }
```

to

```
 public string fullName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName + " " + lastName;
            }
        }
```

After doing so, this guard will evaluate to `true`

```
if (person.fullName == "John Doe")
```

Comment: @TomCatt thanks.  Don't forget to accept this answer if so

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix is to change the line:

```
if (person.fullName == "John Doe")
```

To be

```
if (person.fullName == "JohnDoe")
```

However, the real fix is to update the `fullname` function so it concatenates the first and last name with a space in the middle:

```
public string fullname
{
  get { return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname; }
}
```